# Consume an RSS Feed for Syndication in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I have two jekyll web sites, and I want to syndicate some of the content (one of the categories) from the source blog to the receiving blog via syndication.

I can see how RSS feeds are automatically created with jekyll, but how does one consume them on another site - so that it looks like those posts are from that second site?

Can I do this in jekyll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem is that you jekyll is a static website generator. So you can't do this automatically inside of Jekyll. However, there are two options:

1. You would need to setup a cron script of some sort that pulls down the RSS feed, creates the jekyll files, runs the jekyll command and uploads it to the web. This can all be automated.
2. You could use javascript to display this all. This would basically be writing your own java script (or modifying one you found on the internet). You could use something like this: http://code.google.com/p/jsrss/